# Android. Text, an image, and text again. What Android widgets to use?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, textview, imageview

Now I need to decide what widgets to use. There are a brief text description from an SQLite database and an image from an SD card or from the Internet on the screen.

I think that it would be better to use a single `WebView` to show the content than a `TextView`, an `ImageView`, and a `TextView` again. Are there any better ideas?

Here is a picture I created on Lucidchart.
[image: Text, an image, and text again]

Comment: Максим а в чём проблема использовать связку из TextView, ImageView и опять TextView? Такого готового виджета нету

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either option is fine. If the text in the database is in html format, you should use a webview. If not, you can use two textviews and one imageview.

With the WebView: you can justify the text, but it will not be a very clean solution if you want to resize the image for different screen sizes/resolutions.

Comment: The fewer widgets, the better. That's why I thought of a `WebView`. And besides the `View` class has a lot of children, and I usually use some of them

Answer (score 2):

Using `WebView` is not a good idea, Put the three components within a `RelativeLayout` and in a `ScrollBar` so that you can extend the elements without worrying about the size of the text as well as image size. And also `webView` will not render text perfectly.

Comment: Why use a `RelativeLayout` when a `LinearLayout` would do the job perfectly?

Comment: Yeah that will, But `Relative` is much flexible than linear, So changes can easily accomodated

Comment: It is more flexible, but is also more complex to compute. Check this tweet by Romain Guy about RelativeLayout: https://twitter.com/romainguy/status/369259282769784832

Comment: That you can find for every `widget` in some other blogs , So we cant avoid using it,Dont you use `Relative layout` in android? The above is a simple design you can do by linear , So how you do something complex?

Comment: Romain Guy was one of the lead developer on the Android Graphics and Performance team, so I guess he knows what he is talking about. And you can use `RelativeLayout`, just weight the costs with the benefits. In this particular case, I think it's overkill.